# The name of technique, when main models explicitly split to submodels

Tags: self-study, classification, mixed-model

For my project I work with some kind of random forest. Until recently I've had a huge dateset and I just built one model(one random forest) based on this dateset. The quality of this model was not bad, not not too good as I wished.

However, I've found out that this dataset can be split into several(disjoint) subsets according some external labels, some kind of apriory knowledge. And if separetely train random forest on each of this subsets to get several, as I call it, submodels, and then use these submodels according the label of input data, the whole quality of this "meta-model" increases dramatically. This happens because every submodel can fit to the individual characteristics of subsets.

Now I need to diploma based on this effect and I need to find some articles, which describes this effect. But I can't find any. I heard that this is common technique and many uses it. Perhaps I just don't know the common name of this technique, cause I'm not native English speaker.

Comment: I guess you mean [ensemble models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning)?